# call procedure from a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a procedure which has commit in it (postgresql v11), would like to call his procedure from a function. Getting below error as the procedure has commit, when commit is removed it works fine. Is there any work around to be able to call procedure with transaction control statements from a function (I know function does not support transactions and thats why its failing, but want to know if there is any alternative?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f()
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
BEGIN
raise notice 'Starting Function!!!';
call public.p();
return 'success' ;  
END;
$function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.p() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE src_schema TEXT;
BEGIN
raise notice 'Starting Procedure!!!';
commit;
RETURN;
END;
$$;

-- if the procedure has commit then its failing
imaods=> select public.f();
NOTICE:  Starting Function!!!
NOTICE:  Starting Procedure!!!
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function p() line 5 at COMMIT
SQL statement "CALL public.p()"
PL/pgSQL function f() line 4 at CALL

-- if the commit is removed from the procedure then it works fine
imaods=> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.p() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
imaods$> DECLARE src_schema TEXT;
imaods$> BEGIN
imaods$> raise notice 'Starting Procedure!!!';
imaods$> RETURN;
imaods$> END;
imaods$> $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE
imaods=>
imaods=> select public.f();
NOTICE:  Starting Function!!!
NOTICE:  Starting Procedure!!!
    f
---------
 success
(1 row)
```

Comment: You cannot `commit` in a function nor a procedure called from a function. The proper procedure is to commit calling function or after the procedure is called it the caller is not a function. Do not try to work around for the proper process. You might manage, you might also get some nasty side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) explains that:

> Transaction control is only possible in `CALL` or `DO` invocations from the top level or nested `CALL` or `DO` invocations without any other intervening command. For example, if the call stack is `CALL proc1()` → `CALL proc2()` → `CALL proc3()`, then the second and third procedures can perform transaction control actions. But if the call stack is `CALL proc1()` → `SELECT func2()` → `CALL proc3()`, then the last procedure cannot do transaction control, because of the `SELECT` in between.

The reason is that you cannot have transaction management in PostgreSQL functions.